# RuntimeError: The reset parameter is False but there is no n_features_in_ attribute. Is this estimator fitted?

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, pickle

I am saving a sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer object using pickle. The imputer is fit with

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(train)
```

I then save the imputer with

```
pickle.dump(imputer,open('imputer.pkl','wb'))
```

and load the model in a flask app using

```
imputer = pickle.load(open('imputer.pkl','rb'))
```

I can successfully see the values that should be imputed if I check imputer.statistics_ . However, when I run

```
imputer.transform(test)
```

in my flask app using the imputer loaded with pickle, I get the following error:

"The reset parameter is False but there is no "
RuntimeError: The reset parameter is False but there is no n_features_in_ attribute. Is this estimator fitted?

I am using sklearn version 0.23.1 to fit the imputer and transform the data. Does anyone have any insight on this? Please let me know what other information I can provide.

Answer (score 7):

Reverting sklearn version to 0.22.2.post1 could fix your issue:

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
```

It worked for me.

Comment: So is it a bug with 0.23.1?

Comment: I got same issue with 0.23.2 and 0.24.dev0

Comment: Confirm for 0.23.2.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been introduced with a new public attribute `n_features_in_` for estimators [SLEP010](https://scikit-learn-enhancement-proposals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/slep010/proposal.html) that facilitates a check on the length of the input vector.

This is going to be an issue for anyone who has saved a learned model under 0.22 and is then trying to use it with 0.23 or later. Assuming that you cannot go back and re-learn the model under 0.23, a possible solution is to load the model and then set the `n_features_in_` attribute manually (to the length of `X` vector for `predict()` or `transform()`) after loading.

If the model is a pipeline, set n_features_in_ for each step.